# Javascript convert string to base64 and back again not correct

Tags: javascript, typescript

I noticed that when I convert a javascript string to base64 with [atob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob) and then
back to text with [btoa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa) it returns a string different than where I started. I am wondering why?

Example:

```
btoa(atob('hello world'));
```

The result of this in Chrome dev tools is:
`"helloworlQ=="`

Any ideas why?

Comment: Wrong order, should be `atob(btoa('hello world'))`;

Answer (score 1):

You are using the functions the wrong way around. "hello world" is a valid base64 string, but what you want is atob(btoa())

Answer (score 1):

To convert ASCII to Base64, you need to do

```
btoa("hello world"); // "aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ="
```

To convert Base64 to ASCII, you do

```
atob("aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ="); // "hello world"
```

The names of the `atob` and `btoa` functions are very confusing.